# xcode error " ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient "

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

error " ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient "
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I add a c++ file in my project. The file include some librarys ,here is the list:

```
"Sqlite3.h"
<sqlite3.h>
<iostream>
<sstream>
<set>
<utility>
<stdio.h>
<stdlib.h>
<string.h>
<map>
<list>
<math.h>
<algorithm>
```

what's the problem ? should I have to change some setting in Xcode?

Comment: From where you are open project file ? xcodeworkspace or old project ?

Comment: see this link may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489920/error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-with-cocoapods

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489920/error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-with-cocoapods) not working.My project didn't use CocoaPods @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: from old project. .xcodeproj @BadalShah

Answer (score 0):

First of all for your error :

> please check the Library Search Paths. There are instances when you
>   copy or duplicate a target, Xcode decides that it needs to escape any
>   double quotes " with a '\'. Make sure you remove all the \’s - it
>   should look like this -
>
> [image]

Or another suggetion is ,
Please use cocoapods. It is good for dependency.

Here is full tutorial .

[Install cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32642692/4910767)

Because without using cocoapods you need to do more configuration like you need to set headerpath and etc it's a very tedious work.

After installing cocoapod in your project you need to open it from **.xcworkspace** not from **.xcodeproj** file. check edited image.

[image]

Comment: I think the Library Search Paths is OK. the c++ file is working in Android project and than i got a copy .it's user for reading some data by c++,using sqlite3. i think it maybe work in iOS project too. so just try it.

Comment: I think it is tedious process. Still if you want to try then check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438393/new-to-xcode-cant-open-files-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **Other Linker Flags: -lmysqlclient -lm -lz)**. and refer this link :

[library-not-found-for-lmysqlclient-after-mavericks-upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717589/library-not-found-for-lmysqlclient-after-mavericks-upgrade)

Comment: add it separate three times? " -lmysqlclient ; -lm ; -lz)  "or add it all ? " -lmysqlclient -lm -lz)  ".but both are still that error. T T